# Error on db:migrate in Rails 3.0 and mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to run rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production I get the following error:

```
root@:~/public_html/ticket# rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV='production' --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
!!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:22:in `mysql_connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `new_connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:237:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:191:in `checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:187:in `loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:187:in `checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:186:in `checkout'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:94:in `connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:317:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:97:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:488:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:435:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:435:in `up'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:417:in `migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:151
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

However, in my gem file I have the following:

```
 gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'
```

I added the '< 0.3' because I got the following error otherwise:

`Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/ You have mail. Last login: Tue Aug 23 14:15:09 2011 from adsl-99-142-52-152.dsl.emhril.sbcglobal.net root@:~# dir public_html rvm-installer sources root@:~# cd public_html root@:~/public_html# cd ticket root@:~/public_html/ticket# rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.7) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1 WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x rake aborted! !!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2`

I have tried bundle install with both:

```
 gem 'mysql2', '< 0.3'

 gem 'mysql2'
```

I really don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try replacing existing mysql2 gem inclusion with this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7"
```

Comment: I added that it didn't make a difference.

Comment: can you check the adapter in database.yml. it should be `adapter: mysql2` instead of mysql

Comment: yeah, just figured that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

into app execute

```
install bundle
```

for resolve dependencies gems

Answer (score 0):

WOW. Figured out the problem. http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/19-runtimeerror-missing-the-mysql2-gem My adapter was supposed to be set to mysql2 in yml file.